# How do I programmatically select a node in jsTree and open all parents

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jstree

In a multi-level jsTree how do I select a particular node (probably a leaf node) and expand all it's parents? 
Example:
From this JSFiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/mmeah/fyDE6/) I want to programmatically select Grand Child and have all parent nodes opened.

For some context I'm trying to ensure the user returns to the correct node in the tree if they follow a deep link into my site

Comment: Can we have an example tree in a jsfiddle? Here is a starting point: http://jsfiddle.net/mmeah/fyDE6/

Comment: Good idea, I've updated the question with a clarification and your JSFiddle

Answer (score 5, accepted):

jsTree gives an open_node() function to arbitrarily trigger any node to open. Just scan the tree for non-open parents and open them.

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/mmeah/yyy8W/

```
$("#findChild").click(function(){
    $.jstree._reference(myTree).open_node("#Node_001",function(){;},false);
});
$("#findGrandChild").click(function(){
    var closedParents = $("#Node_003").parents("li.jstree-closed");
    for(var i=closedParents.length-1;i>=0;i--){
        pleaseOpen($(closedParents[i]));
    }
});

function pleaseOpen(thisNode){
    if(typeof thisNode=="undefined") return;
    if(thisNode.hasClass("jstree-leaf") || thisNode.hasClass("jstree-open") ) return;
    $.jstree._reference(myTree).open_node(thisNode,function(){;},true);
}
```

​

Answer (score 2):

Ah ha, I was on the right track but I had a race condition between my deep linking parsing code and the construction of the tree

To select a node and trigger the event

```
$("#tree").jstree("select_node", selector).trigger("select_node.jstree");
```

To do this after the tree has loaded so it works...

```
$("#tree").jstree(...).bind("loaded.jstree", function () 
{
    $("#tree").jstree("select_node", selector).trigger("select_node.jstree");
});
```

Comment: what I have to put in place of that "..."?

Comment: I get error 0x800a01b6 - JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'trigger'

Answer (score 1):

jQuery selection doesn't work on nodes that are not opened [expanded] already. Hence I chose to open [expand] all elements before I did the jQuery selection and then close all the nodes after that.

```js
                // open all nodes to select the desired node using jquery.
                $("#tree").jstree('open_all');
                var node = $("desiredNodeSelector");
                // close all tree since we are done with the selection
                $("#tree").jstree('close_all');
```

Now all we need is just use the 'select_node' jstree api.

```js
$("#tree").jstree('select_node', node);
```