# Open a child node in jsTree

Tags: jquery, jstree

I would like jsTree (3.0.2, with a static ul list, no JSON, no AJAX) to open a child node on load. Actually, the parent node of the current child node.

The raw HTML would look like this:

```
<ul>
  <li id="1">
      <ul>
        <li id="2">
           <ul>
              <li id="3" class="current">
              </li>
           </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <ul>
        <li id="4">
           <ul>
              <li id="5">
              </li>
           </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
  </li>
```

And the desired output is simply

```
1
+-2
 +-3
+-4
```

I have checked about every other post here regarding `open_node`and similar. I haven't managed to get anything to work.

Regarding the post [How do I programmatically select a node in jsTree and open all parents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12013785/how-do-i-programmatically-select-a-node-in-jstree-and-open-all-parents): It seems to be the same question, but I am not sure if it applies to older versions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To make a node initially selected you can set the "**jstree-clicked**" class on the **"a"** element.

Similarly you can set the **jstree-open** class on any "**li**" element to make it initially expanded, so that its children are visible.

JSBIN [Link](http://jsbin.com/qinigu/1/)

Comment: Fantastic - thank you for the complete example! Btw that's not in the documentation, or is it - where should I have looked?

Comment: @Urs It's in the documentation, go to the link http://www.jstree.com/docs/html/ and see the heading "Setting initial state with classes".

Comment: I see. Should have looked better. Thanks again!