# jstree - expand branch to a specific grand-child

Tags: javascript, jstree

I have a (js)Tree which is deep 3 levels or more. Although I have the entire tree data pre-loaded, the tree is collapsed, except for the root node. On a specific js event, I want to expand a particular node (I have its ID/selector). How would I go about it?

At the moment I can only:

```
placeholder.find(".jstree").jstree("open_all");
placeholder.find(".jstree").jstree("select_node", "[data-xxx = '" + yyy + "']");
```

which expands EVERYTHING and selects the given node. I want to achieve the same thing, but expanding only the branch(es) which lead to my node.

To put it in pictures, what my code does is:
[image]

what I want it to do is:
[image]

I am using the latest version of jsTree.

Comment: why you use open_all ?

Comment: If I don't open_all, my node does not appear selected. Or even if it is selected, it is not displayed, because its parent is collapsed.

Comment: try to do this with search plugin ... it does exactly what you want .. https://www.jstree.com/demo/

Comment: hmmm, no it doesn't? it expands the whole tree, at least for me.

Comment: this may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12013785/how-do-i-programmatically-select-a-node-in-jstree-and-open-all-parents

Comment: Thank you, but I don't understand how is that a solution. select_node definitely triggers select_node.jstree by itself, I don't see the point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the `_open_to` function. Provided you have the node ID it should be pretty straightforward:

```
placeholder.find(".jstree").jstree(true)._open_to("NODE_ID_HERE");
```

Here are the docs on this function:
https://www.jstree.com/api/#/?q=_open_to&f=_open_to%28obj%29

**EDIT**: if you also want to select the node, calling `select_node` will be enough, as it will open the parents of the node by default.

Comment: I was hoping you'd chime in.  

    placeholder.find(".jstree").jstree(true)._open_to("node_" + yyy);  
    placeholder.find(".jstree").jstree("select_node", "[data-xxx = '" + yyy + "']");  

got it working for me. For some reason just select_node does not open the parents.

Comment: OK, I understand now. select_node does open the parents, but only if you pass an ID. If you pass a selector (the API says 'mixed'), it does not open the parents.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I will make that clearer - passing a selector will not work, as the selector will not find anything since the node is not in the DOM yet. Use only string IDs (without a `#` prefix) where possible.

Comment: I think the node is in the DOM, because I'm trying to select/open the node on in the "ready.jstree" event callback. Поздрави :)

Comment: jsTree keeps only visible nodes in the DOM, so nodes that are not visible (that have a closed parent) are not in the DOM. Поздрави и от мен :)